# Android Launching Robolectric Unit Tests from Ant?

Tags: android, maven, ant, junit, robolectric

I've been having a hell of a time integrating Robolectric and Ant or Maven, although Ant is a bit preferable because it sits closer to the Android SDKs.

Everything works from within eclipse. Robolectric links and the unit tests run, however when I try to run and build tests from the command line it doesn't seem to work.

With the actual Robolectric-sample application, I attempted to do both maven and ant builds.

The build with ant is successful, but the tests all fail.

**Maven Output**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building RobolectricSample app 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0-beta-1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ robolectricsample ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-13:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) @ robolectricsample ---
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe [package, -m, -J, C:\repos\Tests\robolectric-sample\target\generated-sources\r, -M, C:\repos\Tests\robolectric-sample\AndroidManifest.xml, -S, C:\repos\Tests\robolectric-sample\res, --auto-add-overlay, -I, C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\android.jar]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ robolectricsample ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\repos\Tests\robolectric-sample\src\main\resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\repos\Tests\robolectric-sample\target\generated-sources\extracted-dependencies\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ robolectricsample ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\repos\Tests\robolectric-sample\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-13:unpack (default-unpack) @ robolectricsample ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ robolectricsample ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\repos\Tests\robolectric-sample\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ robolectricsample ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.6:test (default-test) @ robolectricsample ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\repos\Tests\robolectric-sample\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.pivotallabs.api.HttpTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.53 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.tracker.TrackerAuthenticationRequestTest
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowActivity
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowActivityGroup
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowApplication
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowItemizedOverlay
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowListActivity
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowMapActivity
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowPreferenceActivity
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowService
Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowTabActivity
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.361 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.tracker.RecentActivityTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.01 sec
Running com.pivotallabs.ViewEnablingTextWatcherTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.api.ApiGatewayTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.NamesAdapterTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.NotifyDataSetChangedCallbacksTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.GenericAdapterTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.01 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.tracker.AuthenticationGatewayTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.HomeActivityTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.NamesActivityTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.tracker.RecentActivitiesTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.api.ApiResponseTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running com.pivotallabs.injected.InjectedActivityTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.011 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.MultiCallbacksTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running com.pivotallabs.tracker.RecentActivityActivityTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.tracker.RecentActivityRequestTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec
Running com.pivotallabs.ViewVisibleWhileOutstandingCallbacksTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.tracker.SignInDialogTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.views.LoadingTextViewTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.tracker.RecentActivityAdapterTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.pivotallabs.util.StringsTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec

Results :

Tests in error:
  initializationError(com.pivotallabs.api.HttpTest)
  shouldReturnUsernameAndPassword(com.pivotallabs.tracker.TrackerAuthenticationRequestTest)
  shouldHaveUrl(com.pivotallabs.tracker.TrackerAuthenticationRequestTest)
  shouldNotEnableTheViewIfTheAnyOfTheEditTextsContainWhitespace(com.pivotallabs.ViewEnablingTextWatcherTest)
  shouldEnableTheViewWhenAllEditTextsHaveText(com.pivotallabs.ViewEnablingTextWatcherTest)
  shouldDisableTheViewWhenOneOfTheEditTextsHaveEmptyText(com.pivotallabs.ViewEnablingTextWatcherTest)
  initializationError(com.pivotallabs.api.ApiGatewayTest)
  initializationError(com.pivotallabs.NamesAdapterTest)
  onSuccessShouldNotifyDataSetChanged(com.pivotallabs.NotifyDataSetChangedCallbacksTest)
  getCount_shouldReturnListSize(com.pivotallabs.GenericAdapterTest)
  getItem_shouldReturnObjectAtIndex(com.pivotallabs.GenericAdapterTest)
  getView_shouldCallThroughToGetView(com.pivotallabs.GenericAdapterTest)
  getItemId_shouldReturnIndex(com.pivotallabs.GenericAdapterTest)
  initializationError(com.pivotallabs.tracker.AuthenticationGatewayTest)
  initializationError(com.pivotallabs.HomeActivityTest)
  initializationError(com.pivotallabs.NamesActivityTest)
  initializationError(com.pivotallabs.tracker.RecentActivitiesTest)
  initializationError(com.pivotallabs.injected.InjectedActivityTest)
  initializationError(com.pivotallabs.tracker.RecentActivityActivityTest)
  shouldSetProgressBarVisibility(com.pivotallabs.ViewVisibleWhileOutstandingCallbacksTest)
  initializationError(com.pivotallabs.tracker.SignInDialogTest)
  initializationError(com.pivotallabs.views.LoadingTextViewTest)
  shouldRecycleViews(com.pivotallabs.tracker.RecentActivityAdapterTest)
  shouldCreateViews(com.pivotallabs.tracker.RecentActivityAdapterTest)
```

**ant test output**

```
test:
    [junit] Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowActivity
    [junit] Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowActivityGroup
    [junit] Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowApplication
    [junit] Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowListActivity
    [junit] Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowMapActivity
    [junit] Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowPreferenceActivity
    [junit] Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowService
    [junit] Warning: an error occurred while binding shadow class: ShadowTabActivity
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.GenericAdapterTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.HomeActivityTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.NamesActivityTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.NamesAdapterTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.NotifyDataSetChangedCallbacksTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.ViewEnablingTextWatcherTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.ViewVisibleWhileOutstandingCallbacksTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.api.ApiGatewayTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.api.HttpTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.injected.InjectedActivityTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.tracker.AuthenticationGatewayTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.tracker.RecentActivitiesTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.tracker.RecentActivityActivityTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.tracker.RecentActivityAdapterTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.tracker.SignInDialogTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.tracker.TrackerAuthenticationRequestTest FAILED
    [junit] Test com.pivotallabs.views.LoadingTextViewTest FAILED

BUILD FAILED
C:\repos\Tests\robolectric-sample\build.xml:145: Unit test(s) failed.  See reports!
```

The compilation and linking seems good with the samples, but there is still a lot of failing of tests. I would assume that these samples should have 100% success if they are working properly.

Can anyone shed some light about the mysteries within? Can I include junit and robolectric tests in my build scripts, or is this something that isn't supported properly since the android build system undertook those changes a few months ago.

Comment: I have just downloaded and tried on my Windows box (with latest Android SDK), It works for me. Did you modify anything (pom.xml or java source) within Eclipse? what robolectric verison do you use in pom.xml?

Comment: Also using windows, latest SDK, originally changed the SDK to 15 because I didn't have 10 installed, but I installed 10 and changed it back with no change.

Comment: Can you post some surefire reports under ..\target\surefire-reports?